# Was "Carry On Cabby" set in Reading?

Tags: carry-on-cabby

I was watching *Carry On Cabby* this afternoon as it came on the feed, and I loved it still.

I know they filmed it in Windsor and the environs (pretty sure I recognised Windsor Great Park at one point). It was a Shepperton film, so hence to be expected. It was 1963.

On the wall of the manager of the cab firm this film features hangs a map. For one who lives here the map is unmistakable.

Is this deliberate, or did they just happen to use a map of Reading because it's such a convenient shape?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that not one in a thousand of their audience would recognise that map

Comment: Quick search leads to [this comparison image](https://imgur.com/a/tkulMBg) (I don't know if I grabbed the correct image from the office though). Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @OldPadawan Not the one I was thinking of. There's a local map of Reading, in the manager's (Sid James's) office, covering a distance of about 5 or 10 miles. The shape of roads and railways along with an obvious river running through it makes it unmistakable. The one in the canteen is a large scale map of south east England.

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: @HorusKol Tetsujin has posted up a good one. Even at that resolution it's pretty distinctive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Carry Ons were predominantly Pinewood, btw, not Shepperton, which definitely influenced their choices of locations.

I think what's common about all the ones set 'somewhere around London' is they never really said where they were exactly. They tend to have exteriors shot west of London for anything suburban, A41, A40, A4 & environs [pre corridor, of course] for ease of access, anywhere from Aylesbury down to Slough, but as 90% of their audience wouldn't recognise them, they just kept it all as generic as possible.

As Pinewood is off the M40 and Shepperton near the M3 - both just off what is now the M25, which wasn't even a twinkle in the planner's eye back then - that would explain why they chose slightly more northern locations than Shepperton, who would go off further into Surrey for their locations.

At the time, Reading wasn't a quick 20 minutes down the M4 [traffic allowing], it would have been a bit of a slog, but that someone in props would have a map of Reading isn't too surprising. That the audience of the time would recognise it as such is a far smaller chance than today - few people drove or owned cars, and of those few would have intimate knowledge of that exact map. It's not like today, where everyone has a car with sat nav or a constant eye on Google Maps for where they're going.

For those not familiar with the area, here's a [Google Maps ref](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.6389604,-0.7325445,11.12z?entry=ttu) of the west edge of London and out into the home counties.

<sup>Exactly what it shows you will depend on your screen area, of course, but it's a start. At that zoom level Pinewood is near Uxbridge and Shepperton near Chertsey. You'll have to swipe/zoom around a bit;)</sup>

Regardless of where it's *meant* to be set, I found a fairly comprehensive list of all the locations used; predominantly Windsor, and Pinewood itself, of course, including a street literally over the road from the studio entrance [as it was in those days. They moved and enlarged the entrance in recent years].
https://www.reelstreets.com/films/carry-on-cabby/

I also grabbed a low-res screenshot from the film, showing the map in the office. I don't know either Windsor or Reading well enough to be able to tell. Looking at both on modern Gooagle Maps doesn't help me either.

[image]

Comment: I expect the trains were rather more the way to get back and forward between Reading and London than the roads, considering the direct nature of the route from Paddington (the route even got namechecked by Supertramp), but I note your point about the relative inaccessibility of the place compared to how it is now.

Comment: Was that 'Rudy'? I could never identify all the names, except Bristol Temple Meads at the end. I can't imagine an entire film crew, lights, cameras, props, etc etc travelling to loc by train - it would make a Carry On film of its own ;))

Comment: Despite being a quiet town, Reading isn't exactly a backwater either - it's on the main coach road (A4) from London to Bristol. And traffic was a lot less congested then.

Comment: @Tetsujin "The 19:45 train for Bristol Temple Meads will depart from Platform Two,
calling at Reading, Didcot, Swindon, Chippenham, Bath Spa and Bristol Temple Meads.
Passengers for Amberley change at Didcot."

Comment: @HorusKol Reading's not quiet! It's a lively old place, especially when I'm out on the old razzle dazzle.

Comment: @PrimeMover - I'd never have got that in 1973. Back then I'd never heard of most of those places - Northerner, didn't move to London until my 30s, early 1990s.

Comment: I was a student and stayed for a few years after graduation ('97 to '06) - it's a quiet town :) Purple Turtle and After Dark notwithstanding